# find html table data through for loop work it's way through multiple lists in pandas (python 3)

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

Hello I have a html that I am trying to work through multiple lists to collect data for apartment rental rates.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
locations = ['Dallas-TX', 'Denver-CO', 'Tampa-FL']
types = ['Apartments', 'Townhomes']
bedrooms = ['studios', '1-bedroom', '2-bedroom','3-bedroom','4-bedrooms']

dfs = []
for typ, location, bedroom in x(types, locations, bedrooms):
    df = pd.read_html('https://www.apartments.com/{typ}/{location}/studios/'.format(typ = typ, location = location, bedroom = bedroom))[-1]
    df['location'] = location & type & bedroom
    dfs.append(df)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs). reset_index(drop=True)

df
```

what I want is for it to loop through the lists as such that is would give me an output, as an example, of:

```
Dallas-TX Apartment Studio    price
Dallas-TX Apartment 1-bedroom price
Dallas-TX Apartment 2-bedroom price
Dallas-TX Apartment 3-bedroom price
Dallas-TX Apartment 4-bedroom price
Dallas-TX townhome studio      price
Dallas-TX Townhome  1-bedroom price
Dallas-TX townhome 2-bedroom  price
Dallas-TX townhome 3-bedroom price
Dallas-TX townhome 4-bedroom price
Denver-CO Apartment Studio Price
Denver-CO Apartment 1-Bedroom price
Denver-CO Apartment 2-Bedroom price

and so on:
```

I can't think of any way that I can do this, but feel that Pandas is the way to go but thought about BeautifulSoup as well for the collection of the data but am stuck, as I have gone down multiple avenues with this one.

Does anybody have any insights that may be useful. I think I may be over thinking the code here.

Thanks in advance and have an awesome day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can build a Cartesian product of the lists
- the URL you have provided is not returning, hence commented out code for getting HTML

```
locations = ['Dallas-TX', 'Denver-CO', 'Tampa-FL']
types = ['Apartments', 'Townhomes']
bedrooms = ['studios', '1-bedroom', '2-bedroom','3-bedroom','4-bedrooms']

dfs = []
for c in pd.merge(pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(locations, columns=["locations"]).assign(foo=1), 
         pd.DataFrame(types, columns=["types"]).assign(foo=1), on="foo"),
         pd.DataFrame(bedrooms, columns=["bedrooms"]).assign(foo=1), on="foo").drop(columns="foo").values:
    print(c)
#     df = pd.read_html('https://www.apartments.com/{typ}/{location}/{bedroom}/'.format(typ = c[1], location = c[0], bedroom = c[2]))[-1]
#     df['location'] = "-".join(c)
#     dfs.append(df)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs). reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for your response, I should have clarified, there may be multiple of each line that I gather from the site so I am going to need that to be variable to. Do you have any ideas? By the way, I couldn't get it to pull up any tables either, which is weird because it is definitely pulling up tables in the code when I look at the website.